# React native for desktop web

Tags: react-native

Quick simple question, we are in the process of engaging a development firm to build a react native frontend, Magento 2 backend mobile app using REST APIs to have the sites communicate with each other.

The solution was originally mobile only and was developed for IOS, Android, and Mobile web.  My question is can the solution in react native be extended to the desktop web?  some of the B2B features are being requested from us to be available on desktops.

How do we extend the functionality to desktop web and only user react native?

Comment: Use `react js` instead `react native`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the promising [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)